# Getting undefined when I call the props of ReactNative GooglePlacesAutocomplete api on another component

Tags: ios, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, react-native

I'm new to working with RN and I'm trying to use the
[ReactNativeGooglePlaceAutocomplete](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete) module on the **GoogleMapSearch** class component to pass its data object props to another **GoogleMapView** class component that uses the [ReactNativeMaps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps) module. After numerous tries (Majorly wired the props as stateful objects) but still unsuccessful
, I keep getting this error: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined (i.e the props passed to **GoogleMapView** component is undefined). Overall, my intuition is that with the help of these two libraries, a user can type in the name of a place and the map will refocus to the searched location or return places around the searched location. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks. Below are the snippets of code from the two components:

**1st Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';
import GoogleMapView from './GoogleMapView';



class GoogleMapSearch extends Component {

//   constructor(props){
//   super(props);
//   this.state = {
//     data:[],
//     details:null
//   };
//   this.onSearchPress = this.onSearchPress.bind(this);
//
// }
//
// onSearchPress(data,details){
//   return(
//         (data,details = null) => {
//         console.log("dataObj Log: ",data);
//         console.log("detailsObj Log: ",details);
//         this.setState({ data: data , details: details })
//        <GoogleMapView searchRegion= {this.state.details} />
//       }
//     );
// }



  render(){

    const homePlace = {description: 'Home', geometry: { location: { lat: 48.8152937, lng: 2.4597668 } }};
    const workPlace = {description: 'Work', geometry: { location: { lat: 48.8496818, lng: 2.2940881 } }};

    return(
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        placeholder='Enter Location'
        minLength={2}
        autoFocus={false}
        fetchDetails={true}
        onPress={(data,details = null) => {
                console.log("dataObj Log: ",data);
                console.log("detailsObj Log: ",details);
                // this.setState({ data: data , details: details })
               <GoogleMapView searchRegion= {details} />
              }}
        query={{
                // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
                key: API_KEY,
                language: 'en', // language of the results
                types: '(cities)', // default: 'geocode'
              }}
        styles={{
          textInputContainer: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            borderTopWidth: 0,
            borderBottomWidth:0
          },
          textInput: {
            marginLeft: 0,
            marginRight: 0,
            height: 38,
            color: '#5d5d5d',
            fontSize: 16
          },
          predefinedPlacesDescription: {
            color: '#1faadb'
          },
        }}
        currentLocation={true}
        nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch' // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
        // GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={{
        //   // available options for GoogleReverseGeocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
        // }}
        GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
          // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
          rankby: 'distance',
          // type: 'gym',
        }}
        predefinedPlaces={[homePlace, workPlace]}
      />
);
}


};

export default GoogleMapSearch;
```

**2nd component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, Image, TextInput } from 'react-native';
let {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import Hamburger from 'react-native-hamburger';
import somethingSearch from './SearchBar';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchLocation } from '../actions';
import GoogleMapSearch from './GoogleMapSearch';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';






class GoogleMapView extends Component {

  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       region: {
         latitude: 34.034818,
         longitude: -118.456037,
         latitudeDelta: 0.005,
         longitudeDelta: 0.005,
       },
       markers:[
         {latlng: {latitude: 34.011927, longitude: -118.467255},
           image: require('./images/something.png'),
           photo: require('./images/something.png'),
           title: "something accepted" , description: "we are here"},
         {latlng: {latitude: 34.034818, longitude: -118.456037},
           image: require('./images/something.png'),
           photo: require('./images/something.png'),
           title: "something accepted" , description: "we are here"},
         {latlng: {latitude: 34.01536, longitude: -118.496945},
          image: require('./images/something.png'),
           photo: require('./images/something.png'),
           title: "something accepted" , description: "we are here"},
       ],
       active: true,
       term: "",

     };
     this.onRegionChange = this.onRegionChange.bind(this);
     this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    //  this.onSearchSubmit = this.onSearchSubmit.bind(this);
   }


   onInputChange(text){
     console.log("onInputChange text obj: ",text)
     this.setState({ term: text })
   }

   onRegionChange(region) {
     console.log("onRegionChange 1st region obj: ",region)
     this.setState({ region:{ latitude:this.props.searchRegion.geometry.location.lat ,longitude: this.props.searchRegion.geometry.location.lng } });
   }

  //  onSearchSubmit(){
  //    console.log("onSearchSubmit fetchLocation obj: ", this.state.term)
  //    console.log("inside onSearchSubmit")
  //    this.props.fetchLocation(this.state.term);
  //      this.setState({term:''});
  //         console.log("after fetchLocation")
  //  }

   render() {
  let coordinates = this.state.markers.map(marker => marker.latlng);
  // const rad_num = 100;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <Hamburger active= { this.state.active } type="cross" onPress={() => this.setState({ active: !this.state.active })} />
          <GoogleMapSearch />
        </View>
      <MapView style={styles.map} region={this.state.region}
        onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}>
        <MapView.Circle center={this.state.markers[0].latlng}
         radius={1000} strokeWidth={5} fillColor="#0f0a"/>
        <MapView.Polyline coordinates={coordinates}
          strokeWidth={5} strokeColor="#00fa"/>
        <MapView.Polygon coordinates={coordinates}
          strokeWidth={5} strokeColor="#00fa" fillColor="#0aaa"/>
        {this.state.markers.map((marker, i) => (
          <MapView.Marker key={i} coordinate={marker.latlng} title={marker.title} description={marker.description}>
            <View style={styles.pin}>
              <Image style={styles.pinImage} source={marker.image}/>
              <Text style={styles.pinText}>
                {marker.title}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <MapView.Callout>
              <View style={styles.callout}>
                <Image style={styles.calloutPhoto} source={marker.photo}/>
                <Text style={styles.calloutTitle}>{marker.title}</Text>
                <Text>{marker.description}</Text>
              </View>
            </MapView.Callout>
          </MapView.Marker>
        ))}
      </MapView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Latitude: {this.state.region.latitude}{'\n'}
          Longitude: {this.state.region.longitude}{'\n'}
          LatitudeDelta: {this.state.region.latitudeDelta}{'\n'}
          LongitudeDelta: {this.state.region.longitudeDelta}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
},
burger: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
},
map: {
  width: width,
  height: height*2/3
},
pin: {
  backgroundColor: '#fffa',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  borderColor: 'black',
  borderWidth: 2,
  padding: 5,
  borderRadius: 10
},
pinImage: {
  width: 25,
  height: 25
},
pinText: {
  color: 'green'
},
callout:{
  flex: 1,
  paddingRight: 10,
  paddingBottom: 10,
  marginRight: 10,
  marginBottom: 10
},
calloutPhoto:{
  flex: 1,
  width: 166,
  height: 83
},
calloutTitle:{
  fontSize: 16,
}
});

// function mapStateToProps(state){
//
//   return { location:state.location };
// };


export default GoogleMapView;
```

Comment: Does this log 'details': `console.log("detailsObj Log: ",details);`?

Comment: @AdamPatterson withe the code above, I get this error on my console : Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined . However, when I comment out this line of code: this.setState({ region:{ latitude:this.props.searchRegion.geometry.location.lat ,longitude: this.props.searchRegion.geometry.location.lng } }); on the **GoogleMapView** component, I'm was able to console log the data and details object but that doesn't resolve the errors or achieve the functionality I'm looking for. Any ideas?